# ImportError: Couldn't import Django inside virtual environment with poetry?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, python-poetry

I created a django project, set up a virtual environment, and added django with `poetry add`.

inside pyproject.toml:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.9"
psycopg2-binary = "^2.9.3"
Django = "^4.0.1"
```

Inside venv I run `poetry show`:

```
asgiref         3.5.0 ASGI specs, helper code, and adapters
django          4.0.1 A high-level Python web framework that encourages rapid development and clean, pragmatic design.
psycopg2-binary 2.9.3 psycopg2 - Python-PostgreSQL Database Adapter
sqlparse        0.4.2 A non-validating SQL parser.
```

When I run command to create an app:

```
  p manage.py startapp users apps/users
```

I get this error:

```
    (base) ┌──(venv)─(tesla㉿kali)-[~/Documents/projects/graphql/graphenee]
└─$ p                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    1 ⨯
Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 13:09:58) 
[GCC 7.5.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
>>>
```

venv is set, activated, django is installed but I am still getting this error. Inside virtual envrionment I start python shell and import django:

```
    Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 13:09:58) 
    [GCC 7.5.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import django
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

Django is also globally installed and when I start the python shell in global environment, I can import django:

```
Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep 16 2021, 13:09:58) 
[GCC 7.5.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>>
```

Comment: Activate your environment and check installed packages by `pip list`

Comment: @ManzurulHoqueRumi pip list does not show listed packages with poetry

Comment: Then try this command `poetry show`  https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#show

Comment: @ManzurulHoqueRumi poetry show, shows added packages correctly

Comment: ```poetry add Django```

Comment: Django is already added

Comment: please check you are using the write the virtual env, I am telling this because poetry create a virtual env with a fancy name something like ```project_name_vh6g6_jy2s``` unlike ```venv```

Comment: @shivankgtm from docs:  poetry will first check if it’s currently running inside a virtual environment. If it is, it will use it directly without creating a new one.

Comment: @shivankgtm when i run 'poetry env info', it shows "tesla/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/graphenee-CXeG5cZ_-py3.9"

Comment: what happens when, while in venv, you try `import`ing of the other packages that are **not** also globally installed?  what happens when you run `python -m site`?  Do you see an entry ending with `/site-packages` , under `sys.path`?  not the one you also see in  `USER_SITE` entry.  if you `cd` there, do you see a `django` directory?

Comment: @JLPeyret import psycopg2-binary, does not work. import site, works. sys.path returns "'/home/tesla/Documents/projects/graphql/graphenee/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages'"

Comment: don't confuse the pip name for the package name.  `import psycopg2` is what you want to do in Python.   if you `cd /home/tesla/Documents/projects/graphql/graphenee/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages` you should see a django and psycopg2 directories, using something like `ls -1 | egrep -i  'django|psyco'`

Comment: @JLPeyret import psycopg2, did not work neither

Comment: I don't use poetry but once it is done doing its job, the venv should behave like other VMs.  But sometimes packages that are *also* installed globally get treated in unexpected fashion when in a venv.  anyway, what does your file system contain, in that site-packages you quoted just above?

Comment: @JLPeyret inside side-packages, I dont see  psycopg2 or django. Looks like poetry is not addng here. I think there is a conflict between venv and poetry.

Comment: how about you try this.  #1 deactivate the venv.  #2 uninstall the **global** Django.  #3 reactivate the venv.  #3 install the **local** Django.  #4 does import django now work?  you can do the same with psycopg2-binary instead, less stuff than django.  I suspect you have a case of "it's already installed globally so I don't need to reinstall it locally" going on.  now, who is getting that wrong I dunno.

Comment: @JLPeyret the point of venv, to install the different versions inside different projects. i already installed different package version in different venvs before.  So I dont think that that is the issue but i will try it later

Comment: Yilmaz I agree.  But sometimes a globally installed package means the venv does not consider a local install necessary as well.  Can you paste us the output of `python -m site` minus anything sensitive like username?  I have just  spent plenty time of messing with global vs local install glitches which is why i suspect this.

Comment: @JLPeyret are u sure `python -m site` is correct syntax. I get synstax error. I used `sys.path`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have manually created a virtual env in the project directory by e.g. `python -m venv venv`. So now you have one in `/home/tesla/Documents/projects/graphql/graphenee/venv/`.

After that you added some packages with poetry. However, [by default poetry will only look for `.venv` directory](https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#virtualenvsin-project) (note the starting dot) in the project directory. Since poetry did not find a `.venv`, [it created a new virtual env](https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/#using-your-virtual-environment) in `/home/tesla/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/graphenee-CXeG5cZ_-py3.9` and installed the packages you added via `poetry add` there.

The problem is that you try to use the "empty" virtual env in the project directory instead of the one created by poetry. Fortunately with poetry it is very easy to run command, even without activating the venv, just use `poetry run` in the project directory.

To check Django installation:

```
poetry run python
# Executes: /home/tesla/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/graphenee-CXeG5cZ_-py3.9/bin/python
>>> import django
```

To run Django management commands:

```
poetry run ./manage.py startapp users apps/users
```

It will use the virtual env in `/home/tesla/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/graphenee-CXeG5cZ_-py3.9`. You can delete `venv` in the project directory.

Note: if you rather want to use a virtual env in the project directory, then delete `/home/tesla/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/graphenee-CXeG5cZ_-py3.9`, then create one in the project directory by

```
python -m venv .venv`
```

After that install packages with poetry:

```
poetry install
```

Now poetry will use the local virtual env in `/home/tesla/Documents/projects/graphql/graphenee/.venv` when you run a command via `poetry run [cmd]`.

Comment: seems that you deserved +25. Thank you! I cannot believe a  '.' caused that much trouble. I checked the documentation but did not see anything related to .venv.

Comment: Yeah, this information is a [little bit hidden in the docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#virtualenvsin-project). I added the links to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue when my project name was django. The name of the poetry virtual env was then also django, and when I ran poetry add django, nothing happened. When I renamed the project the issue was resolved.

Answer (score -1):

Simple solution:

```
ln -s venv .venv
poetry install
```